# Laravel 5.8.* using GuzzleHttp on production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, laravel-5.8

I'm using GuzzHttp in my laravel project to post some data to an API. In my local enviroment I have to to create my client with the cacert.pem file verification like this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => 'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14\cacert.pem']);
```

But I can't do so on my shared hosting. So, removing that verification:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Results on an internal server error:

```
[2019-06-11 15:17:10] local.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException: Server error: `POST https://pruebas2.mayoristaseguridad.es/tiendaseguridad/02-ConectorLaravelPrestashop/ConectorCategorias.php` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response in /home/admin/web/iberoseguridad.eu/public_html/csv_products/vendor/guzzle/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
```

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: It sounds like the 500 is coming from the remote server. Is that your server, or a 3rd party API?

Comment: Check Error logs to get more info about 500 error

Comment: It was an error from the remote server so @aynber was right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a remote server error, not mine. I just had to communicate that error with the server's maintainer and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, here it goes anyways

> // Disable validation entirely (don't do this!).
>   $client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => false]);

[Guzzle verify api](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify-option)